# Convert a string value into an int

Tags: java, integer, typeconverter, numberformatexception

How to convert string value into int? I am getting `number format exception`.

```
String s = "20.00";
int i = (Integer.parseInt(s));
System.out.println(i);
```

Result should be like `i=20`.

Comment: If there's a decimal in your string, I assume that it may be possible to have an actual decimal after it? In the case of `20.60` what do you expect the integer to be?

Comment: @BBdev Actually, OP's code is the answer on that question. That question says nothing about decimals in the String.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about:

```
int i = (int) Double.parseDouble(s);
```

Of course, `"20.00"` is not in a valid integer format.

Answer (score 2):

> String s = "20.00";

is not valid `Integer` value that is the reason its throwing `NumberFormatException`.

Format your number using either `Double` or `Float` then using narrow casting cast you number to `int` but you may loose precision if exists.

i.e.  `int I = (int) Double.parseDouble(str);`